# Optimization ended up in casting an object at each method call

Tags: c#, design-patterns, optimization, type-casting

I've been doing some optimization for the following piece of code :

```
public void DrawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int color)
{
    _bitmap.DrawLineBresenham(x1, y1, x2, y2, color);
}
```

After profiling it about 70% of the time spent was in getting a *context* for drawing and disposing it.

I ended up sketching the following overload :

```
public void DrawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int color, BitmapContext bitmapContext)
{
    _bitmap.DrawLineBresenham(x1, y1, x2, y2, color, bitmapContext);
}
```

Until here no problems, all the user has to do is to pass a *context* and performance is really great as a *context* is created/disposed one time only (previously it was a thousand times per second).

The next step was to make it *generic* in the sense it doesn't depend on a particular framework for rendering (besides .NET obvisouly).

So I wrote this method :

```
public void DrawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int color, IDisposable bitmapContext)
{
    _bitmap.DrawLineBresenham(x1, y1, x2, y2, color, (BitmapContext)bitmapContext);
}
```

Now every time a line is drawn the *generic* context is casted, this was unexpected for me.

Are there any approaches for fixing this design issue ?

Note :

- `_bitmap` is a [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from WPF
- `BitmapContext` is from [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) library
- `DrawLineBresenham` is an extension method from WriteableBitmapEx

Comment: Making your `bitmapContext` as an `IDisposable` input is probably a really bad idea. There's many many *many* `IDisposable` classes and they'll all be valid, until your try to cast them and then you'll have some major issues. You would better be served by making an specific interface that `DrawLineBresenham` will accept for it's needed methods and require that.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by doing the following : 2 methods like in OpenGL to call before/after drawing operations.

```
public void RenderBegin()
{
    _context = _bitmap.GetBitmapContext();
}

public void RenderEnd()
{
    _context.Dispose();
}
```

No need for an extra DrawLine overload and obviously the method uses the context every time.

But no more ugly cast at every call :D

Answer (score 0):

I would implement it so context is created when `DrawLine` is called for the first time and make the whole class `IDisposable` and dispose the context in there, it if was created of course.

Comment: Sorry I should have added more details, that won't work since to kick an image refresh the context must be disposed.